# Using cardinality of sets to determine a surjection

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I saw a question that had a map $\phi: \mathbb{R}[x] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ defined as $\phi(f)=f(i)$. This question claims the map is surjective *because* $\phi(a+bx)=a+bi$. Is this because this confirms that $\mathbb{R}[x]$ has greater cardinality than $\mathbb{C}$? As $a+bi$ is all the elements in $\mathbb{C}$ but we can have $a+bx+cx^2$ in $ \mathbb{R}[x]$. 
I'm not sure if my understanding is correct here.

Comment: Incomprehensible. Are you asking in the map is surjective but not injective? In any case this only proves that $|\Bbb C|\le|\Bbb R[x]|$ because $|\Bbb C|<|\Bbb R[x]|$ is false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the logic backwards. The argument shows directly that "evaluation at $i$" is a surjection, without any mention or discussion of cardinality. There's no "because" needed in that part of the proof.

Now *because* 
you have found a surjection you know the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is at least as great as the cardinality of $\mathbb{C}$ .

There are other polynomials in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ besides the linear ones. Evaluation at $i$ does map them to complex numbers, so "evaluation at $i$" is not injective.

Comment: So the justification for it being a surjection is that it 'hits' every element in $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @Leonhard Yes. That is after all the definition of "surjection".

Answer (score 1):

by definition $\phi$ is surjective if $\forall z\in \mathbb{C} \;\exists \mathcal{P}\in \mathbb{R}[X]$ such that $\phi(\mathcal{P}) = z = a+ib$
and here the $\mathcal{P}$ is simply $a+bx$